# android studio "Could not create connection to database server" ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, android, sql, android-studio

He probado a cambiar las versiones de los conectores y nada, no funciona. He probado a crear projectos nuevos y nada, he rehecho las BBDD en Workbench en xampp en heidi todas iguales mismo puerto en localhost pero nada, desde programas en Java normal si acceden pero usando la misma clase y conector en Android Studio no funciona y es que nada de lo que he visto me funciona y me preguntaba si alguien podría solucionarmelo por que llevo con este problema 2 meses ya y no sé que hacer, he visto y me han comentado varias personas que habia que hacerlo por servicios de bbdd en red y lo estoy haciendo con el servicio de CleverCloud pero me sigue dando el mismo error y no he encontrado a nadie capaz de solcionarmelo en ningun lado ni si quiera aqui los que me respondieron me dieron una solucion que funcionara[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podríamos ayudarte si nos muestras en tu pregunta cómo estás intentando conectarte a la BD.

Comment: Creo que necesitas añadir al codigo antes de llamar a DriverManager:  
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Como consejo puedo decirte que el problema no siempre es lo obvio, muchas veces los mensajes de error que muestra la consola al ejecutar tu código suelen ser el mismo para una serie de varios problemas relacionados entre sí, por ejemplo, comparar un edit text de la siguiente manera: 
if ( EditText.getText().equals( "Hola" ) ...
No saldrá ningún error pues es una sentencia válida, sin embargo, es claro que falta añadir " .toString() " al comando para que funcione correctamente.
Ningún IDE te ayudará con ese tipo de problemas, así que revisa bien todo, puede ser incluso el driver o una " ñ ".

Comment: Intenta poner el log con los errores que te da, por favor. Es imposible saber qué puede estar mal sin ver los errores/logcat.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que funciona la conexión de esa manera?, he visto demasiados videos y al parecer todos usan php para realizar la conexión, también podría ser porque necesitas otorgarle el permiso de usar internet a tu app

Comment: Hola te deje la Manera con que resolví este problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383219/46896

Comment: Si lo que quieres es conectarte a una **base de datos remota** desde Android (entiéndase por *remoto* en otro equipo que no será el dispositivo donde instalarás la App de Android, aunque estén uno al lado del otro o en la misma red), lo que se suele hacer es programar la conexión en el servidor que aloja a la base de datos y hacer peticiones desde Android (o sea, programar un WebService o una API **en el servidor** y consumirla **desde Android** mediante una URL). Las conexiones se manejan desde Android cuando la base de datos es parte de la App (generalmente SQLite).

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tratas de conectarte a localhost el cual funciona desde tu pc

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
```

pero si estas tratandote de conectar desde una aplicaciòn debes publicar un dominio o permitir exponer la conexiòn de tu pc mediante una ip:

```
"jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.x.x:3306/"
```

Revisa [¿Como puedo acceder a mi localhost desde mi dispositivo Android?](https://www.flipandroid.com/cmo-puedo-acceder-a-mi-localhost-desde-mi-dispositivo-android.html)

Comment: estoy usando el workbench y la base de datos la tengo en el localhost igualmente he probado aponer 127...... , ambas opciones con el puerto tambien y nada me da el mismo error

Comment: es que 127.0.0.1 es la ip de localhost, revisa el articulo que agrego en mi respuesta.

Comment: que va no funciona de hecho empezo a cerrarse la base de datos y tuve que volver al principio no se por que otra cosa tambien es que deje de tener internet he tenido que reiniciar y volver a dejarlo como estaba, ahora mismo estoy viendo un video que lo explica mas claro pero no me termina de funcionar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lM2vDPPx4Xg

Comment: comentas " empezo a cerrarse la base de datos ", porque no obtienes la información que se muestra en el LogCat, puede ser algo no relacionado a la conexión, es importtante revisar el LogCat.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor programar una API o un Servicio Web en el servidor donde está alojada la BD? ¿Qué sentido tendría conectarse vía JDBC? ¿Es funcional eso? ¿Es factible? En caso de que sea posible, ¿qué podría pasar con las conexiones concurrentes y demás situaciones como miles o millones de usuarios de la App intentando este tipo de conexiones?

Comment: no si el codigo lo he dejado como localhost pero ya he probado eso que dices y nada mismo error

Answer (score 2):

Esto funciona de forma diferente en Android Studio, aqui para conectarte no puedes poner "localhost", como ha dicho el compañero, aqui si utilizas el emulador propio de android tienes que poner "10.0.0.2" como ip, si tienes tu dominio, esa ip o la direccion.
Ademas para conseguir los datos tienes usar una asyntask.

Te paso codigo de un proyecto que me funciona todo correctamente.

```
public class ConnectionClass {
String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String ip = "10.0.0.2";
String baseDatos = "nombreBaseDeDatos";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://";
String un = "root";
String password = "";



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+ip+":3306/"+baseDatos, un, password);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

Aqui esta la parte de una consulta a la base de datos con una AsyntasK, tengo un modelo de User y lo voy añadiendo a un arraylist para utlizarlo despues.

```
 public class GetUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Connection con;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String response = "";
        User user = null;
        String nombre = null;
        int id = 0;
        String email = null;
        String password = null;

        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;


        try {

            con = (Connection) new ConnectionClass().CONN();

            st = (Statement) con.createStatement();

            rs = st.executeQuery("Select *  from users where id > 1");
            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt("id");
                nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                email = rs.getString("email");
                password = rs.getString("password");
                user = new User(id, nombre, email, password);
                users.add(user);
                //baseDatos1.insertaEnBodegas(id, nombre, descripcion, rutaVino, logotipo);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return response;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        //Aqui el codigo de lo que quieras hacer con la consulta
    }
}
```

Y luego para llamar a ese metodo.

```
GetUsers getUsers = new GetUsers();
    getUsers.execute("");
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: lo de la ip que es donde me falla no me funciona poniendola en la bbdd en esa ip ni aunque lo ponga en el codigo me da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

**Mira aquí te dejo un Tutorial:**
[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I33dlFY3qWU)

Es un recurso que he utilizado y me ha funcionando correctamente.

## Código a implementar:

### Sección de PHP

> Constant.php

```php
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "Enginner20");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "apilabsys");
?>
```

> DbConnect.php

```php
<?php
    class DbConnect
    {
        //Variable to store database link
        private $con;
     
        //Class constructor
        function __construct()
        {
     
        }
     
        //This method will connect to the database
        function connect()
        {
            //Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
            include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';
     
            //connecting to mysql database
            $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
     
            //Checking if any error occured while connecting
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                return null;
            }
     
            //finally returning the connection link
            return $this->con;
        }
    }
?>
```

> DbOperation.php

```php
<?php
class DbOperation
{
    private $con;
 
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }
 
    //adding a record to database 
    public function insertUser($cedula, $apellidos, $nombres, $password){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(Cedula, Apellidos, Nombres, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $cedula, $apellidos, $nombres, md5($password));
        if($stmt->execute())
            return true; 
        return false; 
    }

    //fetching all records from the database 
    public function getUser(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Id, Nombres, Correo, Start FROM comment");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Id, $Nombres, $Correo, $Start);
        $artists = array();
        
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array(); 
            $temp['Id'] = $Id; 
            $temp['name'] = $Nombres; 
            $temp['comment'] = $Correo; 
            $temp['start'] = $Start; 
            array_push($artists, $temp);
        }
        return $artists; 
    }
}
```

> index.php

```php
<?php 
    
    //adding dboperation file 
    require_once '../DbOperation.php';
    
    //response array 
    $response = array(); 
    
    if (empty($_POST['Cedula']) && empty($_POST['Apellidos']) && empty($_POST['Nombres']) && empty($_POST['Password'])) {
      $response['error'] = true; 
      $response['message'] = 'Campos Vacios al enviar los datos';

   } else {
      if (isset($_POST['Cedula']) && isset($_POST['Apellidos']) && isset($_POST['Nombres']) && isset($_POST['Password'])) {
         $db = new DbOperation(); 
         if($db->insertUser($_POST['Cedula'], $_POST['Apellidos'], $_POST['Nombres'], $_POST['Password'])){
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'User added successfully';
         }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not add User';
         }
         // }else{
         //     $response['error'] = true; 
         //     $response['message'] = 'Required Parameters are missing';
         // }   
      }else{
         $response['error'] = false; 
         $response['message'] = 'Invalid Request';
      }

   }
    
    //displaying the data in json 
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

> listUser.php

```php
<?php 
    
    //adding dboperation file 
    require_once '../DbOperation.php';
    
    //response array 
    $response = array(); 
   
   //if it is getUser that means we are fetching the records
    $db = new DbOperation();
   $ListComment = $db->getUser();
   if(count($ListComment)<=0){
      $response['error'] = true; 
      $response['message'] = 'No se encontró nada en la base de datos.';
   }else{
      $response['error'] = false; 
      $response['artists'] = $ListComment;
   }
    
    //displaying the data in json 
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

### Sección de Kotlin

> MainRegister.kt

```
package com.example.mysqlbd

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main_register.*
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject


class MainRegister : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_register)

        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        val conexion = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val status = conexion.activeNetworkInfo

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener() {

            if (status != null && status.isConnected) {
                addUser()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Revise su conexion a internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    }

    //adding a new record to database
    private fun addUser() {
        //getting the record values
        val cedula = edtCed?.text.toString()
        val apellido = edtApe?.text.toString()
        val nombres = edtNom?.text.toString()
        val pass = edtPass?.text.toString()

        val url = "http://67.207.91.60/KotlinAPI/v1/index.php"

        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("Cedula", cedula)
                params.put("Apellidos", apellido)
                params.put("Nombres", nombres)
                params.put("Password", pass)
                return params
            }
        }

        //adding request to queue
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }

}
```

> VolleySingleton.kt

```
package com.example.mysqlbd

import android.app.Application
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class VolleySingleton : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    private val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return field
        }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
        request.tag = TAG
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
        @get:Synchronized var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

Comment: ya fue editada la respuesta. @Javifer2

Answer (score 0):

Si Android Studio no está en el mismo localhost y lo tienes en otro equipo de tu red (por lo que entiendo de las direcciones IP que comentas), verifica que al equipo que estés intentando conectarte tenga las conexiones entrantes permitidas y el firewall desactivado para probar.

Luego que tengas acceso, añade las reglas y deberías acceder. También verifica que la SQL esté configurada para acceso híbrido si es que las claves no cumplen con los parámetros de seguridad rigurosos.

Comment: esta todo en el mismo pc